# Using legacy Azure MFA with PhoneFactor, receiving Error 149

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication

We are using what seems to be an old system of Azure MFA with PhoneFactor, which is separate from AD.  It is a fairly straightforward system: we send our certified package with the phone number and PIN to https://pfd.phonefactor.net/pfd/pfd.pl, they call the number, user enters PIN, PIN matches, we get the result and let them in.

However, starting today, every attempt to connect has resulted in a 149 error.  I cannot find ANYTHING about this system online somehow, everything goes to the new AD MFA in Azure, including phonefactor.com.  Is anyone else using this legacy system and encountering, or has encountered, this issue?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to the address in the later email saying the SMS was being turned off (mfa-2waysms@microsoft.com) and they responded that they had sent out notification in July that it was being turned off.  They turned it back on through March in order to implement a new solution.